# visual studio project gives error after rebuilding

Tags: visual-studio

I am able to open a saved copy of my project in visual studio and it runs fine. After I rebuild the project it gives me the following error :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Ajax, Version=3.0.31106.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

this is driving me crazy. please help

Comment: I found the solution here
http://pul.se/Issue-with-dependent-assemblies-when-rebuilding-a-WAP-and-the-Workarounds_Windows-WAP-Rebuild-2PGHES4cuz7,15kmd4l1wKxE

download for you appropirate framework here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/download.ashx

then just follow the instructions to add the value to your registry

Answer (score 1):

Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot this problem.  It shows you where the CLR looked for the assembly.